# Rails 3 aggregate functions with timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, activerecord, aggregate

I want to sum up the differences between two time columns in a table. I'm using the following code but it returns zero because end_time is not getting parsed correctly. Both columns are timestamps.

```
table.sum("end_time - start_time")
```

I found that when I typed in table.sum("end_time"), the sum was 2010. This is odd because there is one row in table with an end_time of "2010-12-18 23:42:30".

Answer (score 0):

You can't "subtract" times unless they are UNIX timestamps...

Just let rails do the work. Write a query like:

```
t = Table.find(:all, :conditions => {...})
t.each do |a|
  puts a.end_time - a.start_time
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems a bit slow because it does all the work in Ruby instead of SQL. I will potentially be working with a large number of items. It sounds like I need to ensure that my ruby time values are Unix Timestamps then.

Comment: I agree. I'd recommend using UNIX timestamps and letting SQL do the work. SQL is way faster